# Outlook rule to filter emails except when sent to me not working if I am in distrubution list

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, email-filter

I have a rule in outlook that will auto delete any email that the subject has "Reassigned to" in it and added the exception titled "except where my name is in the To or CC box". This works if the item is sent directly to me but it does not work when sent to a distribution list that I am part of. I thought about using the "message header contains specific words" but when I looked at the headers for one of the emails sent to a distribution list I am in my email address and name are not in the header so that would not work. How exactly do I get rules to stop filtering emails where I am part of the distribution list

Answer (score 0):

If this is an internal distribution list you have no chance to change something about it.

Check the e-mail header (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/view-the-internet-header-information-for-an-email-message-HA101836448.aspx) of the mail. If the header dosent show you mail address your only chance is to add one more exception to your rule.

Then your rule would go like

If you receive a mail and it contains the subject "blabla" delete this message except the message is addressed directly to you **OR the distibution list**